# What is the need of specifying a stream result's buffer size?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, struts2, struts

```xml
<result name="success" type="stream">
  <param name="contentType">image/jpeg</param>
  <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
  <param name="contentDisposition">filename="${filename}"</param>
  <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
</result>
```

When we download files in Struts 2 why should we specify the buffer size? What is its use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the buffer affects the processing efficiency of the program. In general, only 1024 should be used.

Reference: [Struts](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/stream-result.html)

Comment: 1K is the *default*, not necessarily the "best". For example, if most downloads are large or there's a lot of other work going on, larger buffers may be more efficient. The only way to know what the "best" buffer size is to test under realistic loads with realistically-sized downloads.

Comment: It is not a rule of thumb to use 1024 for buffer size, unless it can be changed by the parameter.